# What is the most effective way to compare similarity of two images (which contain buildings)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, comparison

I have an image comparison problem.

To be more precise, I have a test image (a building taken from outside, could be a house, an apartment, a big public building) and I need to compare it against 100.000 other building images in my DB.

Is there an effective method to output top X images (which are most similar, if not the same) in the most accurate way possible to-date?

A number of StackOverflow answers guided me more towards feature-matching OpenCV but sadly I failed to progress (hitting bad accuracy and therefore roadblocks in terms of a way to improve it).

For instance, this is a test image that I would like to compare (white house - South). [test_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k37Lw.jpg)

and these are the images in my DB [pic1_DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkMKB.jpg) [pic2_DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCPnX.jpg) [pic3_DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SE0m.jpg) [pic4_DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzOvy.jpg) [pic5_DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E84lS.jpg)

The desired/ideal output would be "the test image is the same building as that in Pic1, Pic3, Pic4 and Pic5".

And the test image is different significantly from Pic2.

Thank you all.

Comment: You should start by defining what similarity means to you. Are two slightly different buildings with the exact same color more similar to you than the same building but with different colors because of for example shadows? For you, it will probably be the latter while the computer will look only at the pixels in your picture and will probably think that the former is more similar.

Answer (score 1):

matchTemplate wont work well in this case, as they need exact size and viewpoint match.

Opencv Feature based method might work.  You can try SIFT based method first. But the general assumption is that the rotation, translation, perspective changes are bounded. It means that for adjacent iamge pair, it can not be 1 taken from 20m and other picture taken from 10km away. Assumptions are made so that the feature can be associated. 
[image]

Deep learning-based method might work well given enough datasets. take POSEnet for reference. It can matches same building from different geometry view point and associate them correctly. 
[image]

Each method has pros and cons. You have to decide which method you can afford to use

Regards

Dr. Yuan Shenghai

Comment: given your suggestion above (try using SIFT), how can the results of a SIFT calculation between two images give the answer "these two images are similar by x%" ? Sure, the above images have matches (with lines connecting those matches) ... so is it as simple as saying "if there's >25 or >50 matches, it's a similar image?

Comment: Yes the more inliner matches the more likely the 2 picture are associated. To compute the full similarity score. I suggest find the feature match first. then based on the feature match result. apply Homography transform to rotate/translate one image into another. Then in the common field of view of 2 picture, you can compute  common FOV sift vector difference or even the pure intensity difference will do. Then inverse of the difference is the similarity score. hope this can answer your question

Answer (score 0):

For pixel-wise similarity, you may use `res = cv2.matchTemplate(img1, img2, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) \\ similarity = res[0][0]`, which adopts standard corralation coefficient to evaluate simlarity (first assure two inputted image is in the same size).

For chromatic similarity, you may calculate histogram of each image by `cv2.calHist`, then measure the similarity between each histogram by metric of your choice.

For intuitive similarity, I'm afraid you have to use some machine learning or deep learning method since "similar" is a rather vague concept here.